# How to use spl_autoload_register without params?

Tags: php

I have a following directory structure in my project:

```
Test
--Cats
----Fatty.php // namespace: Test\Cats
--index.php
```

index.php:

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

Test\Cats\Fatty::fattyMeow();
```

The error I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Class 'Test\Cats\Fatty' not found in
>   /var/www/public/Test/index.php on line 9

According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php#92514) comment at php.net, `spl_autoload_register()` should work just fine without any `autoload` function provided if namespaces match the directory structure of the project. So, Why the code above doesn't work? Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I don't see a Techniques folder nor a Grumpy.php

Comment: Sorry, in order to simplify the structure I've modified it a bit

Comment: So your directory is like this: `Test/Cats/Fatty.php` and `Test/index.php`?

Comment: @CodeGodie no, the root dir is Test, which contains index.php and Cats dir

Comment: Ah yes, thats what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this is not working for you is because you are including the name of your main directory `Test` in your namespace. When you do this and you run `spl_autoload` it will think that directory exists as a sibling to `index.php`.

To fix this adjust your namespaces and remove `Test`:

in index.php:

```
Cats\Fatty::fattyMeow();
```

in Fatty.php:

```
namespace Cats;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the error still persists.

Comment: Sorry, I was misspelling the method name. Your solution works like a charm!

Comment: :) Glad I was able to help